# Test Sinatra upload and download binary file using Rspec

Tags: ruby, post, rspec, sinatra, md5sum

I have the following rspec code to test the upload and download of a binary file.  I know I can check for **'content-type'** to verify the file is properly uploaded and downloaded. But how do I run MD5 based on the following to make sure it's actually they are the same file.

```
it "should upload a file" do
  file = Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new("./HelloWorld.bin", "application/octet-stream")
  json = {:md5sum => "0cd74c7a3cf2207ffd68d43177681e6b", :config => "./testconfig.yaml"}.to_json

  post "/upload", :json => json, :file => file
  last_response.should be_ok
  (JSON.parse(last_response.body)["status"]).should be_true
  (JSON.parse(last_response.body)["filename"]).should eq("HelloWorld.bin")
end

it "download a file successfully" do
  filename = "HelloWorld.bin"
  get '/download/' + filename
  last_response.should be_ok
  last_response.headers['Content-Type'].should eq "application/octet-stream"
end
```

Can the **'last_response.body'** be assigned as a binary file in the **get '/download'** ?

Comment: Mark some of your questions as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since last_response.body is a string, you can always run a MD5 checksum directly on a string.

```
  (Digest::MD5.hexdigest(last_response.body)).should eq ("a1cba6369d668ed0ae5e97658c30979a")
```